# Multiplication on the Integers Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, solution-verification, integers

From the construction of the integers from the naturals, I am trying to prove that multiplication on the integers is well defined. Is this valid?

I'm using the following definitions: On the set $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ we define an equivalence relation $∼$ for all $(a,b)∈\mathbb{N×N}$ and $(c,d)∈\mathbb{N×N}$ as

$(a,b) ~ (c,d) :\iff a+d=b+c$

The equivalence class is denoted as $[(a,b)] = {(c,d) \in \mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}  }$

Now, addition and multiplication are defined as:

$[(a,b)] +_{\mathbb{Z}} [(c,d)] := [(a+c,b+d)]$ and

$[(a,b)] *_{\mathbb{Z}} [(c,d)] := [(ac+ bd,ad+bc)]$.

I need to prove that multiplication is well-defined? My initial thought was to try to show that if $[(a,b)] = [(a',b')], [(c,d)] = [(c',d')]$
then $[(ac+bd,ad+bc)] = [(a'c'+b'd',a'd'+b'c')]$ which can be represented as $(ac+bd)+(a'd'+b'c') = (ad+bc)+(a'c'+b'd')$. Would this suffice or is there a better way?

Proof.

$[(a,b)] *_{\mathbb{Z}}[(c,d)] = [(a',b')] *_{\mathbb{Z}}[(c',d')] \iff [(ac+bd,ad+bc)]=[(a'c'+b'd',a'd'+b'c')]$

By $+_{\mathbb{Z}}$: $(ac+bd)+(a'd'+b'c')=(ad+bc)+(a'c'+b'd')$

This feels incomplete. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be describing operations on _pairs_ of integers, not just on the integers. Also, as far as tags/labels go, this is more about abstract algebra than analysis.

Comment: I don't think there's any issue of well-definedness, because you're not choosing representatives of any equivalence classes. Rather, maybe you're supposed to prove associativity, or distributivity, and such? Can you clarify? What situation did this arise in?

Comment: @paulgarrett Obviously there are some important chunks missing, but this looks like the construction of integers out of pairs of naturals $(a,b)$ under the equivalence relation $(a,b) \sim (a',b')$ iff $a+b' = a'+b$, which you'd find early on in a course on foundations of analysis.  This effectively identifies $(a,b)$ with the integer $a-b$.  Then you would arrive at the given definitions for addition and multiplication.

Comment: @ErickWong, maybe... but then the supposed defn of the eq'ce relation seems to define an operation of addition, rather than defining an equivalence relation. True, for there to be an issue of well-definedness, it might be something along the lines of what you say. Otherwise, it looks to me that it is a presentation of $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle$, so the image $(0,1)$ of $x$ squares to $1$...

Comment: @ErickWong You are correct. This is from the construction of the integers from the naturals. I've added some additional information. What is a good way to prove multiplication is well-defined?

Comment: @paulgarrett How would I go about picking and denoting a representative? And then what cases would I have to check?

Comment: Ah, with your changes, you are heading in the right direction. As you say, suppose $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ are in the same equivalence class, and $(c,d)$ and $(c',d')$ in the same equivalence class... write out the (proposed) formula for the two products, and check that those two products are in the same equivalence class.

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm still stuck on what exactly to do next. Do I need to use some algebra to distribute and then cancel terms?

Comment: Yes, a little basic algebra to check that the two different batches of representatives produce outputs, respectively, that are in the same equivalence class (as you defined). There's no heavy lifting, just care in not committing typos...

Comment: @paulgarrett Ok. My professor defined special representatives and then broke up the proof into a few cases e.g. c = d, a = b, a < b and c > d. It seemed like over-complication; do you understand the reasoning behind the cases? Unfortunately, the language barrier (my professor is foreign) affects my intuition, hence why I ask here.

Comment: If you're supposed to be operating in a very primitive situation, not being allowed to assume much about standard operations such as subtraction and so on, I guess you'd have a definition of "subtraction" only in pieces, etc., that could require such cases.

Comment: @blacknapkins7 Nah, I can't see any reason for breaking up this proof into cases since the criterion for equivalence is very straightforward.  But it would be a reasonable thing to do for didactic purposes, maybe there is a different problem that approach is useful.